# How to handle Json object in java web service coming from android side

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

I am implementing web service using Jersey javax web services. I am sending json object from Postman rest client to my web service but i am not able to handle that json in my web service.

```
@POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person login(Person person) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException { 
    Person todo = new Person();
        todo.setValid_user(true);
        return todo;
    }
```

and i am sending json to above function from postman rest client as given below.

```
http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/rest/person/login
```

in raw i am writing my json input as

```
{"Person":[
"valid_user":"true"
"userId":"1",
"UserName":"parag",
"userPassword":"parag123",
"userLocation":"asd",
"userTime":"asda",
"message":"asdasd"
]}
```

but i am getting 500 and 415 error.
Hel me out please.

Person class:

package com.avilyne.rest.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private String userId;
    @JsonProperty("UserName")
    private String UserName;
    @JsonProperty("userPassword")
    private String userPassword;
    @JsonProperty("userLocation")
    private String userLocation;
    @JsonProperty("userTime")
    private String userTime;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("valid_user")
    private String valid_user;




     public String isValid_user() {
        return valid_user;
    }
     public void setValid_user(String valid_user) {
        this.valid_user = valid_user;
    }
     public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
     public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
     public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
     public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
     public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }
     public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }
     public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }
     public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }
     public String getUserLocation() {
        return userLocation;
    }
     public void setUserLocation(String userLocation) {
        this.userLocation = userLocation;
    }
     public String getUserTime() {
        return userTime;
    }
     public void setUserTime(String userTime) {
        this.userTime = userTime;
    }
    @Override
     public String toString() {
        return "Person [userId=" + userId + ", UserName=" + UserName + ", userPassword=" + userPassword
                + ", userLocation=" + userLocation + ", userTime=" + userTime + "]";
    }        
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is your friend.

Comment: Show your `Person` class.

Comment: @Cássio Mazzochi Molin  i have uploaded my person class

Comment: You don't need to annotate your getters and setters with `@JsonIgnore`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson mapper, it will automatically convert json to your 'Person' object and vice-versa.

You just need to update your 'Person' bean and add @JsonProperty and @JsonCreator annotation (go through link below) and jackson will take care of the rest.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

The valid json should be:

`{
"valid_user":"true",
"userId":"1",
"userName":"parag",
"userPassword":"parag123",
"userLocation":"asd",
"userTime":"asda",
"message":"asdasd"
}`

Edit:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Person {

    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private String userId;

    @JsonProperty("userName")
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty("userPassword")
    private String userPassword;

    @JsonProperty("userLocation")
    private String userLocation;

    @JsonProperty("userTime")
    private String userTime;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("valid_user")
    private boolean valid_user;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(@JsonProperty("userId") String userId,
                  @JsonProperty("userName") String userName,
                  @JsonProperty("userPassword") String userPassword,
                  @JsonProperty("userLocation") String userLocation,
                  @JsonProperty("userTime") String userTime,
                  @JsonProperty("message") String message,
                  @JsonProperty("valid_user") boolean valid_user) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
        this.userLocation = userLocation;
        this.userTime = userTime;
        this.message = message;
        this.valid_user = valid_user;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public String getUserLocation() {
        return userLocation;
    }

    public String getUserTime() {
        return userTime;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public boolean isValid_user() {
        return valid_user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "userId='" + userId + '\'' +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", userPassword='" + userPassword + '\'' +
                ", userLocation='" + userLocation + '\'' +
                ", userTime='" + userTime + '\'' +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", valid_user=" + valid_user +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I updated the above json, you missed ',' after valid_user and also I changed "UserName" to "userName" (change it if you want).

Please test it out and let me know if it's working.

Comment: i have tried whatever you have suggested but still i am getiing 415 errror. just go through my Person class i have uploaded it.

Comment: A bit late though, While sending the data, just make sure that thte content type is application/json.

Comment: And If you are still facing the problem, push your code to Git Repo, I will run the complete code on my local system.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is *invalid* (check it using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)):

A valid JSON to consume in your service would be:

```js
{
    "valid_user": true,
    "userId": "1",
    "UserName": "parag",
    "userPassword": "parag123",
    "userLocation": "asd",
    "userTime": "asda",
    "message": "asdasd"
}
```

Mind the `,` after `"valid_user":"true"` and `{}` instead of `[]`.

You won't need `{ "Person": {...} }`.